# SharePoint2010 restore does not restore the tags

Tags: managed-metadata, backup, tagging

I am facing a strange issue. Whenever I take backup of SharePoint site collection and move it from Model Office to Production System, the tags with the documents become inactive. When you open the document properties and have have a look at the tags, you will see that tags are there but are in RED color, if you just delete 1 character the suggestion for the tags show up. This way you can again link the tags back to the documents, but with documents growing to a size of 5000 it is impossible to do this.

I have check the metadata admin configs, metadata existence, terms sets and terms existence, everything is okay, yet the tags do not link up on restoration.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you done a full search crawl after the restore? Seems to me that the tags rely on the Search database.

Comment: Hi Nat, I have taken full backup and restored it, after that crawled the complete system, but nothing worked. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you also restored the Metadata Service database to the Production System? I am pretty sure that the metadata fields store GUID of terms as values and even if the NAMES of terms are same both in Model and Prod if they were created by hand their GUIDs will be different and this way in you Prod the system encounters unknown GUIDs and alerts to you with red. When you correct them by hand the system finds the tags by NAME and replaces its GUID to a correct value.

Comment: Hi Maks, I am not sure if its practical to touch the database over n above the client won't allow us to make any changes in the database as already other Site collections and Applications are running.

Answer (score 2):

Maks is right. If you do not copy the terms along with the site collection, the terms used in the site collection will becone "unbound", unless the termstore in production is an exact copy (labels AND Id's) of the source environment.

A taxonomy field is in essence nothing more than a lookup field, whose source is the termstore. In the site collection there is a hidden list that holds all terms used in the site and the guid i=of the term it is bound to. If the guid of the term in the source (model env.) is different from production, you basically break the link.